# How to switch background-color that is on a PHP input, based on the webpage navigated?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, background-color

I'm making a webpage where each page of it has a different background color.

Also, I'm using a PHP input for the header and the footer, which must change its background either according to the webpage. Problem is, how do I change the background-color of it since it is gonna always call the same include?

I thought about using PHP but I don't know why, it didn't worked. I also thought of using Javascript but I don't know much of it either. Can someone help me please?

The div from the header which I want to change its background-color is right below:

```
<div class = "background-header-top">

    </div>
```

Now on CSS:

```
.background-header-top {
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
background-image: url("pattern-blue.png");
}
```

I want it to be come

```
.background-header-top {
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
background-image: url("pattern-pink.png");
}
```

Comment: How are you deciding on the colours?

Answer (score 0):

You can do in the body:

```
<body style="background-image: url(<?php echo $image;?>);">
```

Or with javascript:

```
var body = document.getElementByTagName("body")[0];
body.style.Background = "url(image);";
```

More on PHP:

```
$base = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

Then in body:

```
<body style="background-image: url(<?php echo ($base == "something.php) ? "image.png" : "image.jpg";?>);">
```

Comment: But why would I do it in the body since I want only one div to change?

Comment: then move it to another div... be creative and don't be afraid to think yourself ;)

Comment: Then change it to your `div` then @user3596108

Comment: I did, but it didn't work. That's why I was asking it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make the color arrays:

```
<?
$input = array("pattern-red.png","pattern-pink.png","pattern-blue.png","pattern-yellow.png","pattern-green.png");

$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);
$bg=$input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
?>
```

Then have your css get bg value from the random:

```
<style>
.background-header-top {
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
background-image: url("<?=$bg?>");
}
</style>
```

So your head:

```
<div class="background-header-top"></div>
```

Haven't tried yet, but should work. Tell me if it's not.

Comment: Give me the whold code please. So I can see what's wrong!

Answer (score 0):

instead of defining background image you can do this in inline. but before you need to get page name using like this

lets consider you need image1.jpg as background when you are on home.php

```
 $currentPage =  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
<div class = "background-header-top" style=" <?php if ($currentPage = 'home.php') { echo 'background-image: url(image1.jpg);'; } else { echo 'background-image: url(image1.jpg);'; } ?> "></div>
```

here is a clean version of the code for you to understand

```
<div class = "background-header-top" style=" <?php

if ($currentPage = 'home.php')
{
    echo 'background-image: url(image1.jpg);';
} else
{
    echo 'background-image: url(otherimage.jpg);';
}

?> ">

        </div>
```

change the code as your requirement. this may work with ease

Comment: It won't work still. Maybe the problem is not your code but something else on my webpage, cause it's too weird that none of my tries have worked :/ but thanks anyway.

Comment: All the answers above worked actually! It was just my Coda that was bugged and wouldn't change the background. When I tried to run it on Safari it went straight away.

Thanks a lot, guys!

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
<?php
$background_colors = array("red", "pink","gold","yellow","orange","green","blue");
$bg = $background_colors[array_rand($background_colors)];
?>

<style>
.background-header-top {
        color:#fff;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px;
        background-color:<?=$bg?>;
}
</style>
<div class="background-header-top">Check this out!</div>
```

If you want to change the color to image, it still works!

Live Demo : http://codepad.viper-7.com/5H39AI